# Upserting into multiple tables from multiples topics using kafka-connect

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am trying to read 2 kafka topics using JDBC sink connector and upsert into 2 Oracle tables which I manually created it. Each table has 1 primary key I want to use it in upsert mode. Connector works fine if I use only for 1 topic and only 1 field in `pk.fields` but if I enter multiple columns in `pk.fields` one from each table it fails to recognize the schema. Am I missing any thing please suggest.

```
name=oracle_sink_prod
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=KAFKA1011,JAFKA1011
connection.url=URL
connection.user=UID
connection.password=PASSWD
auto.create=false
table.name.format=KAFKA1011,JAFKA1011
pk.mode=record_value
pk.fields= ID,COMPANY 
auto.evolve=true
insert.mode=upsert

//ID is pk of kafka1011 table and COMPANY is of other
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the PK are different, just create two different sink connectors. They can both run on the same Kafka Connect worker.

You also have the option of using the key of the Kafka message itself. See [doc](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_config_options.html#data-mapping) for more info. This is the more scalable option, and you would then just need to ensure that your messages were keyed correctly for this to flow down to the JDBC Sink.

Comment: Thanks alot Robin but in future the number of topics will keep on increasing may be upto 100 and to manage 100 connectors, is it a good option ?.  Also we our planning to make our data pipeline realtime using kafka connect as our sources will be multiple oracle database and sink will be an oracle dataware house, wont it be difficult to manage so many connectors ?

Comment: I've updated my answer - you could also use `record_key` option, and make sure your kafka messages are keyed accordingly. What option are you using to pull the data out of oracle? Tools like GoldenGate let you specify the key, you can also use [SMT](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/) in Connect itself to define the keys