# JDBC Sink Connector -upserting into multiple tables from multiples topics using kafka-connect - Follow up

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

This is related to the topic mentioned in the below thread

[JDBC Sink Connector -upserting into multiple tables from multiples topics using kafka-connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46182442/jdbc-sink-connector-upserting-into-multiple-tables-from-multiples-topics-using/62697423#62697423)

I know its a bit older post. But my question is also around the same topic. The difference is I want to remove the suffix from the topic name and pass the remaining string as the table name in the sink connector. How can I achieve that?

If it is using SMT, can you please help to achieve that.

Topic Name: Source1-Emp,Source1-Company

Table Name: Emp, Company

Data load needs to happen from multiple topics to multiple tables using a single sink connector.

Can you please help me to implement that.

MUS

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you edit your question to include an example of the source topic name(s) and the table name(s) that you'd like to load them to?

Comment: Robin - I have edited the question above and updated the topic name and table name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right in your assumption that this can be done with Single Message Transform (SMT). Here's an example:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/sink-postgres-00/config \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/",
        "connection.user": "postgres",
        "connection.password": "postgres",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "Source1-Emp,Source1-Company",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "auto.evolve":"true",
        "transforms":"dropPrefix",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"Source1-(.*)$",
        "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"$1"
    }'
```

Comment: Thank you Robin for the answer. So this config doesn't require this key-table.name.format? Will it automatically take from the "topics" key?

Comment: Per the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html#data-mapping) this config option defaults to `${topic}` and so should not be required

Comment: Thank you Robin for your help!

Comment: No problem. BTW StackOverflow etiquette is to upvote / mark as helpful if you think the answer is :-)

Comment: one more question which is related to this @Robin, How can I make sure that the upsert operation happens for the key specified in the Kafka messages than explicitly define the fields here. basically I am looking for the options for these keys.  "pk.mode": and "pk.fields": I do not want to specify the fields as this is for multiple tables and topics.

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I am having the same issue but my topics have not named any prefix. e.g. `"topics": "users,orders,order_items,order_items_history,products"`

Comment: assuming the connector will pick the correct pk from the registry schema you won't need to add them, although in my experience that didn't work. What did work is creating multiple sink connectors though